# libgdx: android application cannot find the main game class

Tags: android, libgdx

I have created the three projects as described in http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup, and running the desktop version works, but I am getting the error below when I run the android version on the emulator. The main project is in the build path of the android project and eclipse builds everything with no errors. what am I missing?

```
10-31 07:06:47.023: E/dalvikvm(769): Could not find class 'com.mygame.MyGame',
referenced from method com.mygame.MyGameAndroid.onCreate
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have resolved this when I switched the Java compiler for the main project from JavaSE-1.7 to JavaSE-1.6. Do now know why this did not work with JavaSE-1.7. Would appreciate any comments on that.

EDIT: a related post: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2314

Comment: This is the one thing I hadn't tried after so many hours with this ******* issue. Thanks for this.

Comment: This didn't help me. What's even worse is that this project used to work, and suddenly stopped working.

Comment: @ashes999 something must have changed on your system. it cannot just stop working by itself.

Comment: I figured it out. My game class had a subclass which wasn't found, so it appeared like the main game class couldn't be found. Lame.

Comment: But, the newest libGdx for desktop requires jdk 1.7, no? I got exactly the same problem when running libGdx with overlap2D now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened because my core `Game` class derived from a framework `Game` class. The framework class wasn't properly included; since the subclass couldn't be found, Android reported that the main class couldn't be found (since it wasn't fully known).

To solve this, I correctly added my derived framework reference, and everything worked.

Answer (score -1):

In had to check the radio button in the android project properties->Java Build Path-> Order and Export-> main game project. Hope it helps anyone else.