# Loading game onto Android with LibGDX throws NoClassDefFoundError: menu.StateManager

Tags: java, android, eclipse, exception, libgdx

I am using LibGDX on Eclipse to build a game, but when I tried to run it on my Android device, it fails with the following error.

```
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: menu.StateManager
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at com.androiddevice.Device.onCreate(Device.java:11)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2034)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4849)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
01-02 23:56:16.649: E/AndroidRuntime(26921):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The Main project builds successfully as a standalone program, only this Android extension doesn't.

So I know that NoClassDefFoundError probably means that I don't have the right .class file included in the project, but how exactly do I do that here? Am I missing a library or a reference somewhere in my setup?

How my project is set up:
Source:
[image: Source]

Projects:
[image: Projects]

Libraries:
[image: Libraries]

Order and Export:
[image: Order]

Android Files:
https://github.com/EyeWumbo/libgdx_device_v1.1/tree/master/Android

Main Project Files:
https://github.com/EyeWumbo/libgdx_device_v1.1/tree/master/Device

Comment: Please have a look at http://sscce.org/ about how to ask a question.

Comment: Use another service for the pictures, it will help people to understand your problem and give you better advices.

Comment: @axierjhtjz Any recommended services? Dropbox and Tinypic results in broken images. You can open the images in a new tab and they'll show up

Comment: @Niek What information do you want me to provide to make this question clearer?

Comment: Where did you create menu.StateManager? In the project "Device"? or in "DeviceDesktop"? Your buildpath etc looks okay to me

Comment: @noone it is under "Device"

Answer (score 0):

Android (before kitkat) requires java 6 or below.
Make sure that your main project has code compliance of java 6 and not java 7.
This should not be a problem if you have used setup-ui. (But still better to check it).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a similar problem and the fix for me was to change my main project java compiler to 1.6. Just go to properties for main project ---> Java Compiler ---> check "Enable project specific settings" and change the "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6.

Here's some links where I got this from: 
[libgdx: android application cannot find the main game class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950965/libgdx-android-application-cannot-find-the-main-game-class)
http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2314

Hope this helps!